# Show a class of tridiagonal matrices is nonsingular.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm studying for an exam and came across a problem I can't seem to solve.  The problem is as follows.  Show that tridiagonal matrices \begin{equation}\begin{array}{c}A=\left(\begin{array}{cccccc}a_1&c_1\\ b_2&a_2&c_2\\& b_3&a_3&c_3\\&&&\ldots\\&&& b_{n-1}&a_{n-1}&c_{n-1}\\&&&&b_{n}&a_{n}\end{array}\right)\end{array}\end{equation} with the properties  \begin{equation} |a_j|\geq|b_j|+|c_j|, \quad b_jc_j\neq0, \quad j=2,3,\ldots, n-1,\end{equation} and $|a_1|>|c_1|>0$ and $|a_n|>|b_n|>0$ are nonsingular.

My first thought is that the matrix is diagonally dominant so applying Gerschgorin's theorem gives me $|\lambda|\geq 0$.  But since we don't have strict diagonal dominance it appears $\lambda$ could still be $0$ in which case the matrix would be singular.  How do I show $|\lambda|>0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it by induction. Do a single step of Gaussian elimination, getting rid of $b_2$. Now the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix in the lower right satisfies the same condition.

Comment: Okay so this will result in an upper triangular matrix with nonzero diagonals which then gives us that the matrix must be nonsingular?

Comment: That's the idea. Or one way to look at it, anyhow. Or just use the fact that an $n\times n$ matrix whose first column is a non-zero number followed by all zeros is non-singular if the lower right $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix is non-singular.

Answer (score 1):

Although the proof based on the Gaussian elimination is probably simpler, you can actually use the Taussky theorem: if $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is an irreducible matrix and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is an eigenvalue of a boundary point of the union of the Gershgorin discs, then *all* Gershgorin circles pass through the point $\lambda$.

Irreducible diagonal dominance means that the matrix is irreducible (it cannot be permuted to a block triangular form) and diagonally dominant with the strict diagonal dominance satisfied for at least one row, which are exactly the conditions you gave for your tridiagonal matrix. Note that in order to apply directly the Taussky theorem, one would like the diagonal elements to be, e.g., positive. This can be achieved by scaling the "bad" rows by $-1$ which of course does not change the singularity or nonsingularity of the matrix.

As a consequence, an irreducibly diagonally dominant matrix is always nonsingular. If such a matrix is not *strictly* diagonally dominant, then there is a disc which passes through $0$. On the other hand, no disc can contain $0$ as the interior point. Due to the strict diagonal dominance for at least one row, there is a disc which does not pass through $0$. Hence Taussky says, that $0$ cannot be the eigenvalue of $A$.

Original reference:

O. Taussky, Bounds for the characteristic roots of matrices. *Duke Math. J.*, 15:1043–1044, 1948.

You can also find the proof, e.g., in:

R. A. Horn, C. R. Johnson, Matrix Analysis. Cambridge University Press, 1985.

NOTES:

- The irreducible diagonal dominance is stronger than irreducibility and diagonal dominance.